# Configure JDBC Authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Goal:  Add jdbc authentication to spring boot with default security configurations.

Source can be found [here](https://github.com/mosgjig/user)

Per [Spring Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html)

> configure the global AuthenticationManager by autowiring an AuthenticationManagerBuilder into a method in one of your @Configuration classes

and [Spring Security Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc) with example:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

Given the above, added the following ([found here](https://github.com/mosgjig/user/blob/master/src/main/java/com/msyla/usergreeter/user/config/AuthenticationManagerConfig.java)):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthenticationManagerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withDefaultSchema()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ROLE_USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN");
    }
}
```

with resulting error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer@13404f75 to already built object
```

and further up the logs, we can see the auto config doing it's thing when it shouldn't be:

```
2016-02-02 22:52:48.047 DEBUG 30487 --- [ost-startStop-1] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$627430a8@78acaa86}
2016-02-02 22:52:48.074 DEBUG 30487 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.BootGlobalAuthenticationConfiguration : Eagerly initializing {user=com.msyla.usergreeter.user.User$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3cd414fd@73128671, coreConfig=com.msyla.usergreeter.user.core.config.CoreConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30c07250@6ed3c66b}
2016-02-02 22:52:48.095  INFO 30487 --- [ost-startStop-1] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: 5b33158f-156d-43f4-892f-6c452f15e1cc
```

Question:  All that is being asked here is to have default boot configurations with the exception of where the user is being stored, jdbc instead of in memory. Am I doing it incorrectly?  Are the docs wrong?  I have tried several other routes to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much work, I recalled how to properly work with spring, that is to step through their code to get a better understanding in surgically addressing my needs.  With some investigation, determined the class in need of modification/extension.  Resulting in:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthenticationManagerConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

The above will instruct spring to look up via jdbc while keeping everthing else auto configured.

Comment: Thanks a million. You learned me that I may also need to step through their code to surgically address my needs as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to override the default security configuration, make sure you are extending the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthenticationManagerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    // ...
}
```

and remove the prefix ROLE_ on your role definition, it will added automatically by spring.

Comment: Doing the above gets the app up and running (with the exception of removing `.withDefaultSchema()` from authenticationManager.)  However I'm unable to get gain access via Oauth2 since the default security config has been changed.  To reiterate, I only wish to change the auth manager to look into jdbc, the security configurations are fine as auto configured.