# How to Configure OAuth 2.0 in Spring by storing the Auth Codes in DataBase instead of ConCurrentHashMap

Tags: jdbc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Currently I am using Spring Security Oauth2 2.3.2 Release. I want to set up a Authorization Code Grant Type Based Authentication.

I debugged the Spring Security "/oauth/authorize" EndPoint. I found below code

private AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices = new InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices();

I debugged more into the code and I found out that  AuthorizationCodeServices is implementented by 3 Classes .

1) InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices
2) JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices
3) RandomValueAuthorizationCodeServices

Default Implementation of Spring provides the InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices. I want to configure it based on the JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices. Now, for that do I need to write my own endpoint and code or could it be done using any configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure JDBC Authentication in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164589/configure-jdbc-authentication-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @AnantGoswami In the Comment you provided is to configure JDBC based user authentication. In my issue, I want to save the auth codes and access tokens generated from Authorization Code based Oauth 2.0 Authentication in the Database instead of Inbuilt ConCurrentHashMap. Spring does provide the implementation but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this bean to the configs:

```
@Bean
OAuth2AuthorizationService jdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
                                                          RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcOperations, registeredClientRepository);
}
```

and execute the contents of `oauth2-authorization-schema.sql` which comes with the `spring-boot-oauth2-authorization-server`:

```
CREATE TABLE oauth2_authorization (
id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
registered_client_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
principal_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
authorization_grant_type varchar(100) NOT NULL,
authorized_scopes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
attributes blob DEFAULT NULL,
state varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_type varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_scopes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Then I got an error similar to this [JwtAuthenticationToken is not in the allowlist, Jackson issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70919216/2155645) and this is how I resolved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/75874873/2155645