# Jackson Module/Mixin for Spring Session for Custom Written Beans

Tags: spring-session

I am having a similar issue with Spring Session Jackson whitelisting as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919216/jwtauthenticationtoken-is-not-in-the-allowlist-jackson-issue).

But my situation is a bit different, as the project I am working on is setting custom written beans (not standard framework beans) to the session and run into this deserialization problem as Spring MVC tries to read the session attribute.

While I am aware that there is an issue ticket [2305](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/2305), I am hoping the Spring Session project can also perform an annotation scan and register a mixin for all the beans listed by the @SessionAttributes annotation.  Thanks a lot!